# Why not mark val or var variables as private?

Tags: scala, encapsulation

Coming from a java background I always mark instance variables as private. I'm learning scala and almost all of the code I have viewed the val/var instances have default (public) access. Why is this the access ? Does it not break information hiding/encapsulation principle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would help it you specified *which* code, but keep in mind that some example code is in a simplified form to highlight whatever it is that the example is supposed to show you.  Since the default access is public, that means that you often get the modifiers left off for simplicity.

That said, since a `val` is immutable, there's not much harm in leaving it public *as long as you recognize that this is now part of the API for your class*.  That can be perfectly okay:

```
class DataThingy(data: Array[Double) {
  val sum = data.sum
}
```

Or it can be an implementation detail that you shouldn't expose:

```
class Statistics(data: Array[Double]) {
  val sum = data.sum
  val sumOfSquares = data.map(x => x*x).sum
  val expectationSquared = (sum * sum)/(data.length*data.length)
  val expectationOfSquare = sumOfSquares/data.length 
  val varianceOfSample = expectationOfSquare - expectationSquared
  val standardDeviation = math.sqrt(data.length*varianceOfSample/(data.length-1))
}
```

Here, we've littered our class with all of the intermediate steps for calculating standard deviation.  And this is especially foolish given that this is not the most numerically stable way to calculate standard deviation with floating point numbers.

Rather than merely making all of these private, it is better style, if possible, to use local blocks or `private[this]` defs to perform the intermediate computations:

```
val sum = data.sum
val standardDeviation = {
  val sumOfSquares = ...
  ...
  math.sqrt(...)
}
```

or

```
val sum = data.sum
private[this] def findSdFromSquares(s: Double, ssq: Double) = { ... }
val standardDeviation = findMySD(sum, data.map(x => x*x).sum)
```

If you need to store a calculation for later use, then `private val` or `private[this] val` is the way to go, but if it's just an intermediate step on the computation, the options above are better.

Likewise, there's no harm in exposing a `var` if it is a part of the interface--a vector coordinate on a mutable vector for instance.  But you should make them `private` (better yet: `private[this]`, if you can!) when it's an implementation detail.

Comment: What is your opinion of hiding the intermediate steps within a block?  This will be hard to format in the comment system, but basically val standardDeviation = { val sumOfSquares = ... ; val expectationSquared = ... ; var varianceOfSample = ...; math.sqrt(data.length * varianceOfSample/(data.length -1)) }

Comment: @joev - That's a good way to do things--often better, in fact, than leaving the variables private.  No sense having them sitting around taking up space after you're done with them.

Comment: @Rex Kerr `there's no harm in exposing a var if it is a part of the interface` - shouldn't we also make `var`-s a `volatile` when making a part of interface?

Comment: I agree with Rex and JoeV on hiding steps in a block.  I'd like to encourage Rex to edit his post to show the example JoeV posted.

Comment: @idonnie - There's no reason to do that except if you're going to have multi-threaded access to the `var`, and it will somehow all work out okay in the absence of locks.  It's critically important when this is true, but usually a `var` means "this will break if you try to use it with multiple threads at once", so adding `@volatile` won't do anything but slow you down in the single-threaded case.

Comment: @Rex Kerr `var` as a part of `abstract` class, can be later overriden to getter/setter `def`-s. For example I can declare a "configuration" abstract trait (full of independent `var`-s), and in a concrete class, inside `_=` setters, add some notifications on config changes (using Java's `Condition` for example). Oppositely to Java - but so much better! ^)

Comment: @idonnie - Abstract `var`s are short for the getter/setter pair in Scala, so they can be overridden by a getter and setter.  Instantiated vars--even if the class itself is abstract--cannot.

Answer (score 3):

One important difference between Java and Scala here is that in Java you can not replace a public variable with getter and setter methods (or vice versa) without breaking source and binary compatibility. In Scala you can.

So in Java if you have a public variable, the fact that it's a variable will be exposed to the user and if you ever change it, the user has to change his code. In Scala you can replace a public `var` with a getter and setter method (or a public `val` with just a getter method) without the user ever knowing the difference. So in that sense no implementation details are exposed.

---

As an example, let's consider a rectangle class:

```
class Rectangle(val width: Int, val height:Int) {
  val area = width * height
}
```

Now what happens if we later decide that we don't want the area to be stored as a variable, but rather it should be calculated each time it's called?

In Java the situation would be like this: If we had used a getter method and a private variable, we could just remove the variable and change the getter method to calculate the area instead of using the variable. No changes to user code needed. But since we've used a public variable, we are now forced to break user code :-(

In Scala it's different: we can just change the `val` to `def` and that's it. No changes to user code needed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, some Scala developers tend to use default access too much. But you can find appropriate examples in famous Scala projects(for example, Twitter's Finagle).

On the other hand, creating objects as immutable values is the standard way in Scala. We don't need to hide all the attributes if they're immutable completely.

Comment: [*Just for a note*] Actually, `val` doesn't guarantee complete immutability. For objects it just ensures that reference to that object is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to answer the question with a bit more generic approach. I think the answer you are looking for has to do with the design paradigms on which Scala is built. Instead of the classical prodecural / object oriented approach, like you see in Java, functional programming is used to a much higher extend. I cannot cover all the code that you mention of course, but in general (well written) Scala code will not need a lot of mutability.

As pointed out by Rex, `val`'s are immutable, so there are few reasons for them to not be public. But as I see it the immutability is not a goal in itself, but a result of functional programming. So if we consider functions as something like `x -> function -> y` the `function` part becomes somewhat of a black box; we don't really care what it does, as long as it does it correctly. As the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_programming#Immutable_data) writes:

> Purely functional programs typically operate on immutable data. Instead of altering existing values, altered copies are created and the original is preserved.

This also explains the missing closure, since the parts we traditionally wanted to hide away is executed in the functions and thus hidden anyway.

So, to cut things short, I would argue that mutability and closure has become more redundant in Scala. And why clutter things up with getters and setter when it can be avoided?